# Why changing ringer mode in android does not require permissions?

Tags: android

I wrote a code to change the ringer mode:

```
private void changeRingerMode() {
        AudioManager audMangr;
        audMangr = (AudioManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(
                Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        audMangr.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
    }
```

I am surprised that this one does not require any permission, whereas changing the brightness requires one. I tested it on a ginger bread phone.
Any idea why this works this way?